# No handler found for request error while using ParameterHandlerMapping

Tags: spring-mvc, liferay, portlet

I am novice to portlet development using spring mvc on liferay. I am doing POC for my project.
In my jsp page, i sent the request to the controller as follows:-

```
<portlet:renderURL var="myRenderURL">
    <portlet:param name="action" value="accounts"/>
</portlet:renderURL>
```

Currently i want to write functionality for only viewing the page using controller i.e. VIEW mode.
Now when i map the controller using the PortletModeHandlerMapping it works perfectly fine and request does goes to the controller as expected. Following is the code snippet :-

```
**<bean id="portletModeHandlerMapping"
          class="org.springframework.web.portlet.handler.PortletModeHandlerMapping">
    <property name="portletModeMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="view" value-ref="partyAccountsSearchController" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>**
```

But when i want the same functionality using the ParameterHandlerMapping. I am getting following error:-

```
07:46:16,704 WARN  [PageNotFound:1010] No mapping found for current request in DispatcherPortlet with name 'LiferaySpringMVCPortlet', mode 'view', phase 'RENDER_PHASE', session '216338AB54AAF5E16EE373D9B97E640A', user 'null
07:46:16,704 ERROR [DispatcherPortlet:559] Could not complete request
javax.portlet.UnavailableException: No handler found for request
        at org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet.noHandlerFound(DispatcherPortlet.java:1017)
        at org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet.doRenderService(DispatcherPortlet.java:706)
        at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.processRequest(FrameworkPortlet.java:522)
        at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.doDispatch(FrameworkPortlet.java:470)
        at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:233)
        at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:101)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:64)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:92)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
        at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:638)
        at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeRender(InvokerPortletImpl.java:723)
        at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.render(InvokerPortletImpl.java:425)
        at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.render_005fportlet_jsp._jspService(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
        at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl.renderPortlet(PortalImpl.java:3740)
        at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil.renderPortlet(PortalUtil.java:1180)
        at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletUtil.processPortlet(RuntimePortletUtil.java:160)
        at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletUtil.processPortlet(RuntimePortletUtil.java:94)
        at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletUtil.processTemplate(RuntimePortletUtil.java:256)
        at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletUtil.processTemplate(RuntimePortletUtil.java:181)
```

Following is the code snippet which i have written for mapping request to ParameterHandlerMapping:-

```
**<bean id="parameterHandlerMapping"
class="org.springframework.web.portlet.handler.ParameterHandlerMapping">
    <property name="parameterMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="accounts" value-ref="partyAccountsController" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>**
```

Now there is a special thing happening here, if i map the request to defaultHandler in ParameterHandlerMapping, it works. i.e. adding

```
**<property name="defaultHandler" value="partyAccountsController"/>**
```

inside the parameterHandlerMapping bean.

I am not sure if i am missing something while configuring the ParameterHandlerMapping.

Can anyone please let how to what is the issue here while configuring ParameterHandlerMapping.

Any help will be appreicated.

Thanks.

Regards,
-Nayan Parikh

Comment: This is solved now.Actually when i was configuring the defaultHandler in the ParameterHandlerMapping bean, it was working as expected.But this was out of my notice,i thought the code is working only because of default handler.The point here i am trying to make is that when you create the request using portlet:actionURL or portlet:renderURL you need a defaultHandler.When the request is serviced either by actionhandler(handleActionRequest()) or renderHandler(handleRendeRequest) the request will go to the default handler for rendering the default view.Which was missing in my case.Hope this helps.